# Arduino use all Ports ATMega2560

Tags: arduino, atmega

I've built my own PCB with Atmega2560 in it. By mistake, I've assembled some inputs and outputs on pins that Arduino don't use. Although I can still use them with Port Manipulation, I would like to manually add them to pins_arduino.h so I can accomplish a better manipulation using Arrays.

I've tried to that but it doesn't work. Can someone guide me in this?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I've tried to that but it doesn't work. Can someone guide me in this?

You actually need to create your own Arduino target. We'll consider `$ARDUINO` to be the root of your arduino installation (`/usr/share/arduino`, or `/Applications/Arduino.app/Contents/Resources/Java/` or whatever it is on windows...).

So do the following steps:

1. in the `$ARDUINO/hardware` copy the full `arduino` directory into a new one that you can call freely. Usually use your firm or group's name, we'll call it `example` for the purpose of the example ;
2. in the `$ARDUINO/hardware/example/variants` directory, you need to copy the `mega` directory and rename it with your board's name, will call it `thing` for the purpose of the example, you can safely remove all other variants (as they still are in the `arduino` variant directory!) ;
3. now you can edit `$ARDUINO/hardware/example/variants/thing/pins_arduino.h`, in there the arduino pin number is the index of each array, and for each index in each array defines the PIN's parameter. At the end of my post I pasted the relevant parts of that header.
4. and now you can edit `$ARDUINO/hardware/boards.txt`

and make a single entry:

```
###########################################################################
thing.name=Your full product name

thing.upload.protocol=wiring
thing.upload.maximum_size=258048
thing.upload.speed=115200

thing.bootloader.low_fuses=0xFF      // double check that those values are the one you need for the fuses
thing.bootloader.high_fuses=0xD8
thing.bootloader.extended_fuses=0xFD
thing.bootloader.path=stk500v2
thing.bootloader.file=stk500boot_v2_mega2560.hex
thing.bootloader.unlock_bits=0x3F
thing.bootloader.lock_bits=0x0F

thing.build.mcu=atmega2560
thing.build.f_cpu=16000000L
thing.build.core=arduino
thing.build.variant=thing
###########################################################################
```

and now you should be all set! (if I did not forget something :-s)

Here's the relevant parts of pins_arduino.h:

```
const uint8_t PROGMEM digital_pin_to_port_PGM[] = {
    // PORTLIST             
    // -------------------------------------------          
    PE  , // PE 0 ** 0 ** USART0_RX     
    PE  , // PE 1 ** 1 ** USART0_TX     
    PE  , // PE 4 ** 2 ** PWM2  
    PE  , // PE 5 ** 3 ** PWM3  
    PG  , // PG 5 ** 4 ** PWM4  
    PE  , // PE 3 ** 5 ** PWM5  
    PH  , // PH 3 ** 6 ** PWM6  
    PH  , // PH 4 ** 7 ** PWM7  
    PH  , // PH 5 ** 8 ** PWM8  
    PH  , // PH 6 ** 9 ** PWM9  
    PB  , // PB 4 ** 10 ** PWM10        
    PB  , // PB 5 ** 11 ** PWM11        
    PB  , // PB 6 ** 12 ** PWM12        
    PB  , // PB 7 ** 13 ** PWM13        
    PJ  , // PJ 1 ** 14 ** USART3_TX    
    PJ  , // PJ 0 ** 15 ** USART3_RX    
    PH  , // PH 1 ** 16 ** USART2_TX    
    PH  , // PH 0 ** 17 ** USART2_RX    
    PD  , // PD 3 ** 18 ** USART1_TX    
    PD  , // PD 2 ** 19 ** USART1_RX    
    PD  , // PD 1 ** 20 ** I2C_SDA      
    PD  , // PD 0 ** 21 ** I2C_SCL      
    PA  , // PA 0 ** 22 ** D22  
    PA  , // PA 1 ** 23 ** D23  
    PA  , // PA 2 ** 24 ** D24  
    PA  , // PA 3 ** 25 ** D25  
    PA  , // PA 4 ** 26 ** D26  
    PA  , // PA 5 ** 27 ** D27  
    PA  , // PA 6 ** 28 ** D28  
    PA  , // PA 7 ** 29 ** D29  
    PC  , // PC 7 ** 30 ** D30  
    PC  , // PC 6 ** 31 ** D31  
    PC  , // PC 5 ** 32 ** D32  
    PC  , // PC 4 ** 33 ** D33  
    PC  , // PC 3 ** 34 ** D34  
    PC  , // PC 2 ** 35 ** D35  
    PC  , // PC 1 ** 36 ** D36  
    PC  , // PC 0 ** 37 ** D37  
    PD  , // PD 7 ** 38 ** D38  
    PG  , // PG 2 ** 39 ** D39  
    PG  , // PG 1 ** 40 ** D40  
    PG  , // PG 0 ** 41 ** D41  
    PL  , // PL 7 ** 42 ** D42  
    PL  , // PL 6 ** 43 ** D43  
    PL  , // PL 5 ** 44 ** D44  
    PL  , // PL 4 ** 45 ** D45  
    PL  , // PL 3 ** 46 ** D46  
    PL  , // PL 2 ** 47 ** D47  
    PL  , // PL 1 ** 48 ** D48  
    PL  , // PL 0 ** 49 ** D49  
    PB  , // PB 3 ** 50 ** SPI_MISO     
    PB  , // PB 2 ** 51 ** SPI_MOSI     
    PB  , // PB 1 ** 52 ** SPI_SCK      
    PB  , // PB 0 ** 53 ** SPI_SS       
    PF  , // PF 0 ** 54 ** A0   
    PF  , // PF 1 ** 55 ** A1   
    PF  , // PF 2 ** 56 ** A2   
    PF  , // PF 3 ** 57 ** A3   
    PF  , // PF 4 ** 58 ** A4   
    PF  , // PF 5 ** 59 ** A5   
    PF  , // PF 6 ** 60 ** A6   
    PF  , // PF 7 ** 61 ** A7   
    PK  , // PK 0 ** 62 ** A8   
    PK  , // PK 1 ** 63 ** A9   
    PK  , // PK 2 ** 64 ** A10  
    PK  , // PK 3 ** 65 ** A11  
    PK  , // PK 4 ** 66 ** A12  
    PK  , // PK 5 ** 67 ** A13  
    PK  , // PK 6 ** 68 ** A14  
    PK  , // PK 7 ** 69 ** A15  
    // added stuff
    PD  , // PD 4 ** 70 ** D70
    PD  , // PD 5 ** 71 ** D71
    PD  , // PD 6 ** 72 ** D72
    PG  , // PG 3 ** 73 ** D73
    PG  , // PG 4 ** 74 ** D74
    PH  , // PH 2 ** 75 ** D75
    PH  , // PH 7 ** 76 ** D76
    PJ  , // PJ 2 ** 77 ** D77
    PJ  , // PJ 3 ** 78 ** D78
    PJ  , // PJ 4 ** 79 ** D79
    PJ  , // PJ 5 ** 80 ** D80
    PJ  , // PJ 6 ** 81 ** D81
    PJ  , // PJ 7 ** 82 ** D82
    PE  , // PE 6 ** 83 ** D83
    PE  , // PE 7 ** 84 ** D84
};

const uint8_t PROGMEM digital_pin_to_bit_mask_PGM[] = {
    // PIN IN PORT          
    // -------------------------------------------          
    _BV( 0 )    , // PE 0 ** 0 ** USART0_RX     
    _BV( 1 )    , // PE 1 ** 1 ** USART0_TX     
    _BV( 4 )    , // PE 4 ** 2 ** PWM2  
    _BV( 5 )    , // PE 5 ** 3 ** PWM3  
    _BV( 5 )    , // PG 5 ** 4 ** PWM4  
    _BV( 3 )    , // PE 3 ** 5 ** PWM5  
    _BV( 3 )    , // PH 3 ** 6 ** PWM6  
    _BV( 4 )    , // PH 4 ** 7 ** PWM7  
    _BV( 5 )    , // PH 5 ** 8 ** PWM8  
    _BV( 6 )    , // PH 6 ** 9 ** PWM9  
    _BV( 4 )    , // PB 4 ** 10 ** PWM10        
    _BV( 5 )    , // PB 5 ** 11 ** PWM11        
    _BV( 6 )    , // PB 6 ** 12 ** PWM12        
    _BV( 7 )    , // PB 7 ** 13 ** PWM13        
    _BV( 1 )    , // PJ 1 ** 14 ** USART3_TX    
    _BV( 0 )    , // PJ 0 ** 15 ** USART3_RX    
    _BV( 1 )    , // PH 1 ** 16 ** USART2_TX    
    _BV( 0 )    , // PH 0 ** 17 ** USART2_RX    
    _BV( 3 )    , // PD 3 ** 18 ** USART1_TX    
    _BV( 2 )    , // PD 2 ** 19 ** USART1_RX    
    _BV( 1 )    , // PD 1 ** 20 ** I2C_SDA      
    _BV( 0 )    , // PD 0 ** 21 ** I2C_SCL      
    _BV( 0 )    , // PA 0 ** 22 ** D22  
    _BV( 1 )    , // PA 1 ** 23 ** D23  
    _BV( 2 )    , // PA 2 ** 24 ** D24  
    _BV( 3 )    , // PA 3 ** 25 ** D25  
    _BV( 4 )    , // PA 4 ** 26 ** D26  
    _BV( 5 )    , // PA 5 ** 27 ** D27  
    _BV( 6 )    , // PA 6 ** 28 ** D28  
    _BV( 7 )    , // PA 7 ** 29 ** D29  
    _BV( 7 )    , // PC 7 ** 30 ** D30  
    _BV( 6 )    , // PC 6 ** 31 ** D31  
    _BV( 5 )    , // PC 5 ** 32 ** D32  
    _BV( 4 )    , // PC 4 ** 33 ** D33  
    _BV( 3 )    , // PC 3 ** 34 ** D34  
    _BV( 2 )    , // PC 2 ** 35 ** D35  
    _BV( 1 )    , // PC 1 ** 36 ** D36  
    _BV( 0 )    , // PC 0 ** 37 ** D37  
    _BV( 7 )    , // PD 7 ** 38 ** D38  
    _BV( 2 )    , // PG 2 ** 39 ** D39  
    _BV( 1 )    , // PG 1 ** 40 ** D40  
    _BV( 0 )    , // PG 0 ** 41 ** D41  
    _BV( 7 )    , // PL 7 ** 42 ** D42  
    _BV( 6 )    , // PL 6 ** 43 ** D43  
    _BV( 5 )    , // PL 5 ** 44 ** D44  
    _BV( 4 )    , // PL 4 ** 45 ** D45
    _BV( 3 )    , // PL 3 ** 46 ** D46  
    _BV( 2 )    , // PL 2 ** 47 ** D47  
    _BV( 1 )    , // PL 1 ** 48 ** D48  
    _BV( 0 )    , // PL 0 ** 49 ** D49  
    _BV( 3 )    , // PB 3 ** 50 ** SPI_MISO     
    _BV( 2 )    , // PB 2 ** 51 ** SPI_MOSI     
    _BV( 1 )    , // PB 1 ** 52 ** SPI_SCK      
    _BV( 0 )    , // PB 0 ** 53 ** SPI_SS       
    _BV( 0 )    , // PF 0 ** 54 ** A0   
    _BV( 1 )    , // PF 1 ** 55 ** A1   
    _BV( 2 )    , // PF 2 ** 56 ** A2   
    _BV( 3 )    , // PF 3 ** 57 ** A3   
    _BV( 4 )    , // PF 4 ** 58 ** A4   
    _BV( 5 )    , // PF 5 ** 59 ** A5   
    _BV( 6 )    , // PF 6 ** 60 ** A6   
    _BV( 7 )    , // PF 7 ** 61 ** A7   
    _BV( 0 )    , // PK 0 ** 62 ** A8   
    _BV( 1 )    , // PK 1 ** 63 ** A9   
    _BV( 2 )    , // PK 2 ** 64 ** A10  
    _BV( 3 )    , // PK 3 ** 65 ** A11  
    _BV( 4 )    , // PK 4 ** 66 ** A12  
    _BV( 5 )    , // PK 5 ** 67 ** A13  
    _BV( 6 )    , // PK 6 ** 68 ** A14  
    _BV( 7 )    , // PK 7 ** 69 ** A15  
    // added stuff
    _BV( 4 )    , // PD 4 ** 70 ** D70
    _BV( 5 )    , // PD 5 ** 71 ** D71
    _BV( 6 )    , // PD 6 ** 72 ** D72
    _BV( 3 )    , // PG 3 ** 73 ** D73
    _BV( 4 )    , // PG 4 ** 74 ** D74
    _BV( 2 )    , // PH 2 ** 75 ** D75
    _BV( 7 )    , // PH 7 ** 76 ** D76
    _BV( 2 )    , // PJ 2 ** 77 ** D77
    _BV( 3 )    , // PJ 3 ** 78 ** D78
    _BV( 4 )    , // PJ 4 ** 79 ** D79
    _BV( 5 )    , // PJ 5 ** 80 ** D80
    _BV( 6 )    , // PJ 6 ** 81 ** D81
    _BV( 7 )    , // PJ 7 ** 82 ** D82
    _BV( 6 )    , // PE 6 ** 83 ** D83
    _BV( 7 )    , // PE 7 ** 84 ** D84
};

const uint8_t PROGMEM digital_pin_to_timer_PGM[] = {
    // TIMERS               
    // -------------------------------------------          
    NOT_ON_TIMER    , // PE 0 ** 0 ** USART0_RX     
    NOT_ON_TIMER    , // PE 1 ** 1 ** USART0_TX     
    TIMER3B , // PE 4 ** 2 ** PWM2  
    TIMER3C , // PE 5 ** 3 ** PWM3  
    TIMER0B , // PG 5 ** 4 ** PWM4  
    TIMER3A , // PE 3 ** 5 ** PWM5  
    TIMER4A , // PH 3 ** 6 ** PWM6  
    TIMER4B , // PH 4 ** 7 ** PWM7  
    TIMER4C , // PH 5 ** 8 ** PWM8  
    TIMER2B , // PH 6 ** 9 ** PWM9  
    TIMER2A , // PB 4 ** 10 ** PWM10        
    TIMER1A , // PB 5 ** 11 ** PWM11        
    TIMER1B , // PB 6 ** 12 ** PWM12        
    TIMER0A , // PB 7 ** 13 ** PWM13        
    NOT_ON_TIMER    , // PJ 1 ** 14 ** USART3_TX    
    NOT_ON_TIMER    , // PJ 0 ** 15 ** USART3_RX    
    NOT_ON_TIMER    , // PH 1 ** 16 ** USART2_TX    
    NOT_ON_TIMER    , // PH 0 ** 17 ** USART2_RX    
    NOT_ON_TIMER    , // PD 3 ** 18 ** USART1_TX    
    NOT_ON_TIMER    , // PD 2 ** 19 ** USART1_RX    
    NOT_ON_TIMER    , // PD 1 ** 20 ** I2C_SDA      
    NOT_ON_TIMER    , // PD 0 ** 21 ** I2C_SCL      
    NOT_ON_TIMER    , // PA 0 ** 22 ** D22  
    NOT_ON_TIMER    , // PA 1 ** 23 ** D23  
    NOT_ON_TIMER    , // PA 2 ** 24 ** D24  
    NOT_ON_TIMER    , // PA 3 ** 25 ** D25  
    NOT_ON_TIMER    , // PA 4 ** 26 ** D26  
    NOT_ON_TIMER    , // PA 5 ** 27 ** D27  
    NOT_ON_TIMER    , // PA 6 ** 28 ** D28  
    NOT_ON_TIMER    , // PA 7 ** 29 ** D29  
    NOT_ON_TIMER    , // PC 7 ** 30 ** D30  
    NOT_ON_TIMER    , // PC 6 ** 31 ** D31  
    NOT_ON_TIMER    , // PC 5 ** 32 ** D32  
    NOT_ON_TIMER    , // PC 4 ** 33 ** D33  
    NOT_ON_TIMER    , // PC 3 ** 34 ** D34  
    NOT_ON_TIMER    , // PC 2 ** 35 ** D35  
    NOT_ON_TIMER    , // PC 1 ** 36 ** D36  
    NOT_ON_TIMER    , // PC 0 ** 37 ** D37  
    NOT_ON_TIMER    , // PD 7 ** 38 ** D38  
    NOT_ON_TIMER    , // PG 2 ** 39 ** D39  
    NOT_ON_TIMER    , // PG 1 ** 40 ** D40  
    NOT_ON_TIMER    , // PG 0 ** 41 ** D41  
    NOT_ON_TIMER    , // PL 7 ** 42 ** D42  
    NOT_ON_TIMER    , // PL 6 ** 43 ** D43  
    TIMER5C , // PL 5 ** 44 ** D44  
    TIMER5B , // PL 4 ** 45 ** D45  
    TIMER5A , // PL 3 ** 46 ** D46  
    NOT_ON_TIMER    , // PL 2 ** 47 ** D47  
    NOT_ON_TIMER    , // PL 1 ** 48 ** D48  
    NOT_ON_TIMER    , // PL 0 ** 49 ** D49  
    NOT_ON_TIMER    , // PB 3 ** 50 ** SPI_MISO     
    NOT_ON_TIMER    , // PB 2 ** 51 ** SPI_MOSI     
    NOT_ON_TIMER    , // PB 1 ** 52 ** SPI_SCK      
    NOT_ON_TIMER    , // PB 0 ** 53 ** SPI_SS       
    NOT_ON_TIMER    , // PF 0 ** 54 ** A0   
    NOT_ON_TIMER    , // PF 1 ** 55 ** A1   
    NOT_ON_TIMER    , // PF 2 ** 56 ** A2   
    NOT_ON_TIMER    , // PF 3 ** 57 ** A3   
    NOT_ON_TIMER    , // PF 4 ** 58 ** A4   
    NOT_ON_TIMER    , // PF 5 ** 59 ** A5   
    NOT_ON_TIMER    , // PF 6 ** 60 ** A6   
    NOT_ON_TIMER    , // PF 7 ** 61 ** A7   
    NOT_ON_TIMER    , // PK 0 ** 62 ** A8   
    NOT_ON_TIMER    , // PK 1 ** 63 ** A9   
    NOT_ON_TIMER    , // PK 2 ** 64 ** A10  
    NOT_ON_TIMER    , // PK 3 ** 65 ** A11  
    NOT_ON_TIMER    , // PK 4 ** 66 ** A12  
    NOT_ON_TIMER    , // PK 5 ** 67 ** A13  
    NOT_ON_TIMER    , // PK 6 ** 68 ** A14  
    NOT_ON_TIMER    , // PK 7 ** 69 ** A15  
    // added stuff
    NOT_ON_TIMER        , // PD 4 ** 70 ** D70
    NOT_ON_TIMER        , // PD 5 ** 71 ** D71
    NOT_ON_TIMER        , // PD 6 ** 72 ** D72
    NOT_ON_TIMER        , // PG 3 ** 73 ** D73
    NOT_ON_TIMER        , // PG 4 ** 74 ** D74
    NOT_ON_TIMER        , // PH 2 ** 75 ** D75
    NOT_ON_TIMER        , // PH 7 ** 76 ** D76
    NOT_ON_TIMER        , // PJ 2 ** 77 ** D77   // PCINT 11
    NOT_ON_TIMER        , // PJ 3 ** 78 ** D78   // PCINT 12
    NOT_ON_TIMER        , // PJ 4 ** 79 ** D79   // PCINT 13
    NOT_ON_TIMER        , // PJ 5 ** 80 ** D80   // PCINT 14
    NOT_ON_TIMER        , // PJ 6 ** 81 ** D81   // PCINT 15
    NOT_ON_TIMER        , // PJ 7 ** 82 ** D82
    NOT_ON_TIMER        , // PE 6 ** 83 ** D83
    NOT_ON_TIMER        , // PE 7 ** 84 ** D84
};
```

Comment: Thanbks! I actually managed to make it work 2 hours after my question, but that's exactly what I've done. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I have done just this, for a project. You can pull my GITHUB [Mega2560](https://github.com/mpflaga/biofeedback.project) for the variant, board and pins_arduino.h file. It basically does what zmo stated. That said it is for IDE 1.5.0, where 1.5.5 has an added directory for platform AVR/SAM.

You will want to read about [1.0.5](http://code.google.com/p/arduino/wiki/Platforms) and [1.5.5](https://github.com/arduino/Arduino/wiki/Arduino-IDE-1.5---3rd-party-Hardware-specification)

On my new projects I use 1.5.5, where the boards.txt supports a "uno.build.board=AVR_UNO" tag that makes compiles auto identifying real easy.

See [this discussion about 1.5.5 boards.txt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20868853/arduino-at-11-0592mhz-modify-timer0-delaymicroseconds/20870461#20870461) for example

Comment: Thanks, I actually made it to work 2 hours after my post, but thanks for the help!

Comment: actually, if you addressed all the pins, it's not a `mega` anymore so you should give your board a different variant name! Otherwise, you're right to point out about 1.5.5, but there are other more important modifications to come in the design of libraries (but I'm getting offtopic). Though, we may consider having a "standard" full pinout for the 2560 so we can ease development for future projects.