# Arduino 1.0.6: How to change compiler flag?

Tags: c++11, arduino, command-line-arguments, arduino-ide, compiler-flags

I'm currently working on a project using Arduino 1.0.6 IDE and it does not seem to accept C++11 `std::array`. Is it possible to change the compiler flag to make this work?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using the IDE is very difficult to do that.

I would advise you to go *full command line* by using [Sudar's great Arduino Makefile](https://github.com/sudar/Arduino-Makefile).

This way you'll be able to customise the compiler flags to your liking.

I've also created the [Bare Arduino Project](https://github.com/ladislas/Bare-Arduino-Project) to help you get started. The documentation covers a lot points, from installing the latest `avr-gcc` toolchain to how to use the repository, compile and upload your code.

If you find something missing, please, feel free to fill an issue on Github so that I can fix it :)

Hope this helps! :)

Answer (score 10):

Add custom compiler flags to platform.local.txt. Just create it in the same directory where platform.txt is. For example:

```
compiler.c.extra_flags=
compiler.c.elf.extra_flags=
compiler.S.extra_flags=
compiler.cpp.extra_flags=-mcall-prologues -fno-split-wide-types -finline-limit=3 -ffast-math
compiler.ar.extra_flags=
compiler.objcopy.eep.extra_flags=
compiler.elf2hex.extra_flags=
```

In this example C++ flags will make large sketch smaller. Of course, you can use your own flags instead. Since platform.local.txt does not overwrite standard files and is very short, it is very easy to experiment with compiler flags.

You can save platform.local.txt for each project in its directory. It will NOT have any effect in project's directory, but this way if you decide to work on your old project again you will be able to just copy it to the same directory where platform.txt is (typically ./hardware/arduino/avr/) and continue work on your project with project-specific compiler flags.

Obviously, using Makefile as ladislas suggests is more professional and more convenient if you have multiple projects and do not mind dealing with Makefile. But still, using platform.local.txt is better than messing with platform.txt directly and an easy way to play with compiler flags for people who are already familiar with Arduino IDE.

Comment: Very useful answer! Thanks.  For Windows ArduinoIDE, it would be around: `.../Users/XXXX/Documents/Arduino/hardware/espressif/esp32/`.

Comment: Should this work with VS-Core? or only with Arduino IDE?

Answer (score 8):

You can use `#pragma` inside the `*.ino` file so as not to have to create the local platforms file:

```
#pragma GCC diagnostic warning "-fpermissive"
#pragma GCC diagnostic ignored "-Wwrite-strings"
```

For other ones, see [HERE](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Pragmas.html).

Comment: This is definitely the best answer when you want to avoid warnings. No need to mess with anything in the libraries or gitted repos. For a long list of other methods, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3378560/how-to-disable-gcc-warnings-for-a-few-lines-of-code).

Comment: warning: '-fpermissive' is not an option that controls warnings [-Wpragmas]
    1 | #pragma GCC diagnostic warning "-fpermissive"

Answer (score 5):

Yes, but not in 1.0.6, in 1.5.? the `.\Arduino\hardware\arduino\avr\platform.txt` specifies the command lines used for compiling.

One can either modify this file directly or copy it to your user `.\arduino\hardware\...` directory to create a custom platform. As not to alter the stock IDE. This will also then exist in other/updated IDEs that you can run. You can copy just the platform file and boards.txt. And have your boards.txt file link to the core: libraries as not to have a one-off. See

Reference: [Change CPU speed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20868853/arduino-at-11-0592mhz-modify-timer0-delaymicroseconds/20870461#20870461), [Mod New board](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/3546/how-to-modify-arduino-boards-txt-to-support-new-mcus/3554#3554)

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to add the `-fpermissive` flag.
Under Linux here what I have done with success

The idea is to replace the two compilers `avr-gcc` and `avr-g++` by two bash scripts in which you add your flags (`-fpermissive` for me)

With root privilege:

- rename the compiler `avr-gcc` (present in /usr/bin) `avr-gcc-real`
- rename the compiler `avr-g++` (present in /usr/bin) `avr-gcc-g++-real`

Now create to bash scripts `avr-gcc` and `avr-g++` under `/usr/bin/`

script `avr-gcc` contains this line:

```
avr-gcc-real -fpermissive $@
```

script `avr-g++` contains this line:

```
avr-g++-real -fpermissive $@
```

As you may know `$@` denotes the whole parameters passed to the script. Thus all the parameters transmitted by the IDE to compilers are transimitted to your bash scripts replacing them (which call the real compilers  with your flags and the IDE one)

Don't forget to add executable property to your scripts:

```
chmod a+x avr-gcc
chmod a+x avr-g++
```

Under Windows I don't know if such a solution can be done.

Comment: obviously you can do scripting on Windows. It can do anything Linux can do