# Arduino/C++ Enum declaration position dependent

Tags: c++, enums, arduino

I am working on my first arduino project, where I came across the following behavior I would like to understand. The following code compiles with no issues:

```cpp
enum TestEnum {TestValue1};
void test(){}
void setup(){}
void loop(){}
void foo(TestEnum &testArg) {}
```

But switching the first two lines

```cpp
void test(){}
enum TestEnum {TestValue1};
void setup(){}
void loop(){}
void foo(TestEnum &testArg) {}
```

results in the following errors when compiling:

```
D:\Path\to\Arduino-Sketches\foo\foo.ino:5:10: error: variable or field 'foo' declared void
 void foo(TestEnum &testArg) {}
          ^~~~~~~~
D:\Path\to\Arduino-Sketches\foo\foo.ino:5:10: error: 'TestEnum' was not declared in this scope
D:\Path\to\Arduino-Sketches\foo\foo.ino:5:10: error: note: suggested alternative: 'isalnum'
D:\Path\to\Arduino-Sketches\foo\foo.ino:5:20: error: 'testArg' was not declared in this scope
D:\Path\to\Arduino-Sketches\foo\foo.ino:5:20: error: note: suggested alternative: 'test'
 void foo(TestEnum &testArg) {}
                    ^~~~~~~
                    test
```

Can anyone explain why an enum needs to be defined before all functions? Is this an Arduino IDE thing? If it is a general C++ thing, what is the rational for this?

Comment: It seems the error messages do not correspond to the provided code. For example in the first message there should be ino:5:6: instead of ino:5:10:

Comment: +Vlad That is indeed weird. I ran it again, but I do get ino:5:10, and not ino:5:6.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow I've verified it with a fresh install of the latest Arduino IDE w/ the Uno board. Odd.

Comment: arduino has its preprocessor and it might mess it up like it's looking for the first function and adds all the generated prototypes before it - check the generated .cpp file instead

Comment: In general it's a good practice to declare global variables at the beginning of the file, before functions, like in example 1.  Why is it required in this case I don't know.

Comment: @TedLyngmo Yeah, I mentioned that both snippets are well-formed in the answer below so this is an arduino specific thing.

Comment: https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/66530/class-enum-was-not-declared-in-this-scope/66536

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's caused by Arduino preprocessing from .ino to .cpp file. It's for "convenience" reasons so begginers doesn't have to add prototypes (you can only use functions after they are declared or defined) and of course #include <Arduino.h>. So:

```
void test(){}
enum TestEnum {TestValue1};
void setup(){}
void loop(){}
void foo(TestEnum &testArg) {}
```

Will be preprocessed as:

```
#include <Arduino.h>
#line 1 "C:\\Users\\mikusm\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\arduino_modified_sketch_446733\\sketch_feb19a.ino"
#line 1 "C:\\Users\\mikusm\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\arduino_modified_sketch_446733\\sketch_feb19a.ino"
void test();
#line 3 "C:\\Users\\mikusm\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\arduino_modified_sketch_446733\\sketch_feb19a.ino"
void setup();
#line 4 "C:\\Users\\mikusm\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\arduino_modified_sketch_446733\\sketch_feb19a.ino"
void loop();
#line 5 "C:\\Users\\mikusm\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\arduino_modified_sketch_446733\\sketch_feb19a.ino"
void foo(TestEnum &testArg);
#line 1 "C:\\Users\\mikusm\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\arduino_modified_sketch_446733\\sketch_feb19a.ino"
void test(){}
enum TestEnum {TestValue1};
void setup(){}
void loop(){}
void foo(TestEnum &testArg) {}
```

And as you can see all the function prototypes (declarations) apeared before any function definition (eg before test() {})

When you moved the function definition after the enum definition, it results into this:

```
#include <Arduino.h>
#line 1 "C:\\Users\\mikusm\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\arduino_modified_sketch_473375\\sketch_feb19a.ino"
enum TestEnum {TestValue1};
#line 2 "C:\\Users\\mikusm\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\arduino_modified_sketch_473375\\sketch_feb19a.ino"
void test();
#line 3 "C:\\Users\\mikusm\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\arduino_modified_sketch_473375\\sketch_feb19a.ino"
void setup();
#line 4 "C:\\Users\\mikusm\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\arduino_modified_sketch_473375\\sketch_feb19a.ino"
void loop();
#line 5 "C:\\Users\\mikusm\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\arduino_modified_sketch_473375\\sketch_feb19a.ino"
void foo(TestEnum &testArg);
#line 2 "C:\\Users\\mikusm\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\arduino_modified_sketch_473375\\sketch_feb19a.ino"
void test(){}
void setup(){}
void loop(){}
void foo(TestEnum &testArg) {}
```

Notice where the `enum TestEnum {TestValue1};` ended in real .cpp file

Possible workarounds:

- namespaces
- multiple files: sketch.ino + sketch.cpp where ino contains only library includes (for auto detection) and sketch.cpp contains everything (all includes including Arduino.h and all libraries, loop, setup). EDIT: seems ino file can be empty and the libraries are detected from other source files

Comment: Great answer! What a horrible "convenience" extension :-)

Comment: Yes, it had lot of troubles with new c++ language features like constexpr and so on. For example platformio doesn't do this and you have to have cpp file including Arduino.h and either declare functions before use or having whole implementations before use (definitions)

Comment: _"constexpr and so on"_ - I was just thinking about that. I know I was able to change from C++11 to a later standard the last time I started the IDE (which was a very long time ago) but now I can't seem to find it. Perhaps I need to hack some configuration file manually? Edit: Yep, that seems to be it: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73003610/7582247

Comment: The -std=c++11 is in the Arduino cores for some time (it might vary for other "vendors" :D). And you can always create another file (like not_Ino.cpp) and have the loop and setup there :D However you'll have to add library includes into both, otherwise auto detection might not be working :D

Comment: I just modified `platform.txt` and set it to `-std=gnu++17` which is the latest standard the old gcc 7.3.0 based compiler supports. :-) The IDE now uses that as default so `if constexpr (...)` etc. works.

Answer (score 2):

The code *should* compile so it seems to be a bug in the environment.

A workaround is to put `foo` in a `namespace`:

```cpp
void test(){}
enum TestEnum {TestValue1}; 

void setup(){}
void loop(){}

namespace {
  void foo(TestEnum &testArg) {}
}
```

or put all the functions and other definitions that Arduino is not requiring in a `namespace`:

```cpp
namespace {
  void test(){}
  enum TestEnum {TestValue1}; 

  void foo(TestEnum &testArg) {}
}

// leave these in the global namespace:
void setup(){}
void loop(){}
```

Answer (score 1):

> Can anyone explain why an enum needs to be defined before all functions? If it is a general C++ thing?

Both the snippets are **well-formed** and this seems to be a arduino IDE specific thing.

> Is this an Arduino IDE thing?

Yes **this seems to be a arduino IDE specific thing.**